# How to play video from bag file in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an video in my bagfile.

I can play the video by rosrun image_view image_view image:=basler_node/image_color.

I want to show this video in separate GUI using QT. how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101096/how-to-play-video-from-bag-file-in-qt?/) by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_image_view ?

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on 2013-11-15**:
Thank you. nice.